# Why are my login/register buttons still working when empty?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created an app with a simple login/register form that will give a user a token and stores it in `localStorage`. I also have a logout function in place which will remove the token from storage. Everything works as planned however, if I press the form button to login or to register, it will still give access to the dashboard until the page is refreshed.
Login.js

```
const Login = ({ setAuth }) => {
  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({
    email: '',
    password: '',
  });

  const { email, password } = inputs;

  //Handle form inputs
  const changeHandler = (e) => {
    setInputs({
      ...inputs,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  };

  //Form submit handler
  const submitHandler = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      const body = { email, password };

      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/auth/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify(body),
      });

      //Retrive token from URL
      const parseRes = await response.json();

      //Save token in local storage then give user authorization
      localStorage.setItem('token', parseRes.token);

      setAuth(true);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className='container'>
        <h1 className='text-center my-5'>Login</h1>
        <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
          <input
            type='email'
            name='email'
            placeholder='Email'
            className='form-control my-3'
            value={email}
            onChange={(e) => changeHandler(e)}
          />
          <input
            type='password'
            name='password'
            placeholder='Password'
            className='form-control my-3'
            value={password}
            onChange={(e) => changeHandler(e)}
          />
          <button className='btn btn-success w-100'>Login</button>
        </form>
        <Link to='/register'>Register</Link>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

In the console after trying to login with an empty form, I get 2 errors from my server side routes: `POST http://localhost:5000/auth/login 401 (Unauthorized)` and `GET http://localhost:5000/dashboard/ 401 (Unauthorized)`. These errors are expected and working as they are supposed to.

Is there something wrong with my form or could this be in another area of my code?

Comment: what does this line mean "if I press the form button to login or to register, it will still give access to the dashboard until the page is refreshed" ? also, why not exchange token as cookies?

Comment: @PranayNailwal I have 3 pages, a login page, a register page, and a dashboard page. The dashboard is a protected route. So after clicking the submit buttons with an empty form, it will put me into the dashboard screen. Since the form is empty, I don't get a token, so upon refresh I get redirected back to login. And It was my first time doing authentication, I just chose one. I don't know the benefits of one over the other

Comment: 1st things 1st, add form validations (at least `required` will do). 2nd Handle all http codes by adding a check `if (!response.ok) { const error = (data && data.message) || response.status;  return Promise.reject(error);}` before processing a response. 3rd only proceed further to  `setAuth(true);` after validating the `parseRes.token`

Comment: also, since dashboard is a protected route, if user manually enter the url for that page, it should give auth error. so handle that condition as well on the dashboard loading in `componentDidMount()`